# Are subsequences of low discrepancy sequence also low discrepancy?

Tags: monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

Given a low discrepancy sequence x1 ... xN, lets say I randomly select a subsequence x100 ... x200, will this subsequence have low discrepancy? Will those points "fill" up the space uniformly?

If not are there any sequence out there that does that? I am looking for a sequence that has low discrepancy every N points and low discrepancy overall. For example x1...x100, x101...x200 are low discrepancy subsequences and overall x1...xN is also low discrepancy. Do such sequences exists?

In my case this will be in very high dimension, 100~500 dimensions.

Comment: Indeed this is possible. Look for the keyword "scrambling" in the context of quasi monte-carlo.

Comment: Isn't scrambling just makes the sequence non deterministic? Do you mean I rescramble a sequence every N points?